# Are question like how much money can I do, etc. allowed

Tags: discussion

I am a very basic poker player. My goal is to play poker to make money (as many other people). What keeps me from really dive into it is not really knowing how much money I could be doing and how shoul I procede.

I guess generic question as:

- How much money can I do playing poker
- What book/method should I follow

are stupid and spammy

On the other hand, one question of the kind:

- How hard is to earn 500$ a month playing poker, how much time would
  it cost me?

Might have a quite definite answere. Is such question good?

Answer (score 2):

"How much money can I make" is not a good question - it has been rehashed so many times on 2+2 and the answer is always it depends, with some broad varying range thrown in to appease people.

The simple fact is that variance means that you'll never know your true win rate, and an question like "how hard is it to earn $x" will always have an answer like "Well, if you play y stakes, with an initial bankroll of z, and your playing style earns an average of theta, and your standard deviation is sigma, then there is a p percent chance that you'll make $x in any given time period."

That answer isn't really helpful, mainly because the people asking it probably won't know what stakes they're playing, probably won't have an initial bankroll, won't know their average earn, and definitely won't know their standard deviation.

Answer (score 0):

No.

That is bad subjective "How hard is x", not definitively answerable, and its is likely to generate a discussion.

There is no need to change the rules to address that question.